# What are __CUDABE__ and __CUDA_LIBDEVICE__ for?

Tags: gcc, cuda

Let's say I'm interested on preprocessing (with `gcc`) hpp/cpp files which include CUDA kernel declarations. I want the preprocessor to not to scrap the `__global__` specifier, otherwise I wouldn't be able to link against the definition in the `.cu` file.

For instance, a file `t1.hpp`:

```
__global__ void foo(int* v, int n);
```

And preprocess with:

```
gcc -E t1.hpp  -I/usr/local/cuda/include -include cuda_runtime.h
```

But the result scraps **global** !:

```
...    
# 1888 "/usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime.h"
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "t1.hpp"
 void foo();
```

But if I define `__CUDABE__` (on CUDA 8.0) or `__CUDA_LIBDEVICE__` in CUDA 9.0+ i amb able to keep that information:

```
gcc -E t1.hpp  -I/usr/local/cuda/include -include cuda_runtime.h -D__CUDABE__
```

Final result:

```
...
# 1888 "/usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime.h"
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "t1.hpp"
__attribute__((global)) void foo();
```

So my question is, what is `__CUDABE__` and `__CUDA_LIBDEVICE__` for and if what could be the side effects.

I've also seen that clang defines those macros in `__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h`. Is this then this something safe to do?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not documented anywhere, it's some sort of an internal flag they use (which can, as you've noticed change between the compilers), so you probably shouldn't rely on it. It is defined in `crt/host_defines.h`, which is not very well documented, so I cannot decipher what it means.

Is there any reason why you cannot preprocess the file with `nvcc`?
This should do what you want, and it invokes `gcc` with correct parameters (at least on my system):

```
nvcc -E --x=cu t1.hpp`
```

If you cannot use `nvcc` for whatever reason, you can always call it in verbose mode (`nvcc -E -v --x=cu t1.hpp`) and see which flags it sets. On my linux system with CUDA 9.1 I get:

```
gcc -std=c++14 -D__CUDA_ARCH__=300 -E -x c++ \
    -DCUDA_DOUBLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS -D__CUDACC__ \
    -D__NVCC__  "-I/opt/cuda/bin/..//include" \
    -D"__CUDACC_VER_BUILD__=85" -D"__CUDACC_VER_MINOR__=1" \
    -D"__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__=9" -include "cuda_runtime.h" \
    -m64 "t1.hpp"
```

However, you'll probably have to do it for each CUDA version you want to use, as these flags can change.

Comment: I'm tied to `gcc` because the compiler infraestructure I'm using always use `gcc` as the preprocessor (it generates an IR from the preprocessed files). `nvcc` calls the `gcc` preprocessor setting `-D__CUDACC__` which is one of the two conditions for enabling the `global` attribute. But since my compiler isn't `nvcc` I think I'll have to use the `-D__CUDA_LIBDEVICE__`. Thanks